# Empty Keychains "1" that cannot be deleted

Tags: macos, keychain

When opening Keychain Access I have a bunch of empty keychains named `1` as well as the normal `login` keychain. These cannot be deleted.

[image: Empty Keychains]

What are they and what are they for? How do I get rid of them? (Should I?)

Comment: Do these keychain files also appear in your ~/Library/Keychains folder?

Comment: Which macOS are you using? If >10.11 than you can use 'Keychain First Aid', which (unfortunatly) has been removed in later macOS Versions

Comment: What msg do you encounter when you attempt to delete these?

Comment: Not an answer, but this is not a good sign. I'd do a clean re-install.

Comment: Those are other user key chains that you don’t have rights to. Are there other accounts on the machine? Normally you wouldn’t be explicitly locked from viewing the key chains.

Comment: Using macOS v10.14.4. There is no way to delete these keychains and as far as I can see, they also do not show up in the keychains folder. No other user accounts on this machine.

Comment: Other possible locations to check are /System/Library/Keychains (you should not edit these) and /Library/Keychains folders.  Keychains that belong to users are in the ~/Library/Keychains folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found that you can press <kbd>delete</kbd> on each of them and remove them. Takes a while if yours is just like mine and had a few hundred but at least you can remove them.

Comment: I also had to restart Keychain Access for it to realise that the empty keychains had in fact been deleted.